# Excel: sorting alphabet with diacritics

Tags: excel, alphabetical-sort

I have a list of vocabulary in Excel in a given language.

The thing is, this language has four diacritical letters: č ǧ š ț, which are letters on their own and are placed after their respective 'mother characters', but Excel ignores them and mixes up diacritic and non-diacritic versions.

So for example I have:

```
sete
ši
sieta
```

When it should be:

```
sete
sieta
[...]
suona
šconda
[...]
ši
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you seen [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_windows8-mso_2013_release/alphabetizing-foreign-language-lists-in-excel/2ab9f5b2-89ee-4ded-86f8-d2f9fe3c2c33) from @Jeeped ?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that might do the trick is to put the letters in a separate table that has 2 columns - letter and sort number.

Then create a helper sort column that looks up the table to give you a sort using vlookup / index match. If it is applicable you might also want to add the remaining characters to make the sorting more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

It will be sorted correctly if your windows reginal settings are set for your country.

Comment: https://imgur.com/IpqZVf5